# Как задизейблить поле, пока не заполнено другое поле?

Tags: angular

поле `input2` должен становиться доступным для заполнения, только когда `input1` заполнено `value`. Как это можно сделать без использования ангуляровских форм

```html
<input-text       class="input1"
                  [ngModel]="titlePanel ? value : ''">
</input-text>
<input class="input2">
```

Comment: `[disabled]="someProperty.length === 0"` ?

Comment: @overthesanity, к сожалению, в моем случае он не подходит. есть ли какой-нибудь другой способ?